# Use for loop to subtract two arrays of objects in Swift or is there a better way?

Tags: ios, swift

We need to subtract two arrays of CGPoint objects using Swift. Specifically, we want to find all the CGPoint objects in array A but not in array B.

Should we just loop through and manually compare elements, or is there a preferred mechanism native to Swift for doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In swift 2, this has changed to:

```
let x = a.filter { !b.contains($0) }
```

Answer (score 6):

Some combination of `filter` and `contains` would do it:

```
let x = a.filter { !contains(b, $0) }
```

This is assuming there are no other characteristics of `a` and `b` you might exploit, such as them both being ordered (in which case it would be more efficient to walk them both in parallel).

Comment: if you want to subtract, the correct answer should use "not contains":
 `let x = a.filter { !contains(b, $0) }` ;)